Could not parse some characters: |(total/4)||floatformat:2
<td>
{% with data.marks1|add:data.marks2|add:data.marks3|add:data.marks4 as total %}
{{ (total/4)|floatformat:2 }}
{% endwith %}


I am making a simple crud application in Django and em repeatedly getting this error.  
Anything I do does not resolve this error

if you think (total/4) means that divide, it's impossible. django template not support.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The error occurs because of the use of the pipe symbol | within the with tag, which Django's template engine cannot parse correctly in that context. Here's how you can fix the issue:
#create a custom filter template:
In your templatetags directory (if you don’t have one, create it), add a new file, e.g., math_filters.py:
 
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.filter
def div(value, arg):
    try:
        return float(value) / float(arg)
    except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
        return None

# Now load the custom filter in your tempalte
{% load math_filters %}
<td>
{% with total=data.marks1|add:data.marks2|add:data.marks3|add:data.marks4 %}
    {{ total|div:"4"|floatformat:2 }}
{% endwith %}
</td>


https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/howto/custom-template-tags/
Django Docs for creating new custom template tags
